# LaTeX Surd Colouring Issues in Manim

Tags: python, latex, manim

I have the following scene:

```
from manimlib.imports import *

class Surds(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        text_1 = TexMobject("\\sqrt{", "a", "\\times", "b", "} ")

        text_1.set_color_by_tex("a", BLUE)
        text_1.set_color_by_tex("b", YELLOW)

        self.play(Write(text_1))
```

Which is meant to write the latex expression

```
\sqrt{a \times b}
```

With `a` coloured blue, and `b` coloured yellow.

Instead, something strange happens. The times symbol is coloured yellow, the 'top' of the surd is coloured blue, and the `b` doesn't render at all:

[image]

I'm certain that the surd is messing things up as the same colouring technique worked as intended in a different scene:

[image]

So how can I get colouring to work with the surd?

**Side note:** I also noticed that adding an additional 'b' on the end of the LaTeX expression makes the penultimate one render, but this isn't really a fix as the `\sqrt` spacing and colouring are still off:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Although this is more of a workaround than a fix, I have noticed that adding parenthesis does seem to make things render correctly. Coding the scene like this:

```
class Surds(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        text_1 = TexMobject("\\sqrt{(","a","\\times","b",")}")

        text_1.set_color_by_tex("a", BLUE)
        text_1.set_color_by_tex("b", YELLOW)

        self.play(Write(text_1))
```

Produces this:

[image]

Ideally it would be possible to do this without additional parenthesis, but if not, this might be the best you can do.